# JSONP callback error: Property 'insertFilmData' of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I Have 3 nested $.ajax calls using JSONP, the first $.ajax calls work in the function but the third fails to execute the call back giving me this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'insertFilmData' of object [object Object] is not a function`

CODE:

```
function searchFilms(film, settings) {
if (film === '') {
    console.log("enter a movie");
} else {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key=XXX',
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'getSearchResults',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
            if (json.images) {
                settings.imageData = json.images;
                getSearchResults(json, settings);
            }
        }
    });

    function getSearchResults(data, settings) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=XXX&query=' + film,
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'deliverResults',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json) {
                if (json.total_results !== 0) {
                    deliverResults(json, settings);
                }
            }
        });

        function deliverResults(data, settings) {
            var results = data.results;
            var html = "<ul id='film-search-results' data-role='listview' data-inset='true'>";
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var result = results[i];
                var filmId = result.id;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + filmId + '?api_key=XXX&append_to_response=' + settings.extras,
                    async: false,
                    jsonpCallback: 'insertFilmData',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function(json) {
                        if (json) {
                            settings.html = html;
                            insertFilmData(json, settings);
                        }
                    }
                });

                function insertFilmData(data, settings) {
                    var poster_base_url = settings.imageData.base_url;
                    var poster_size = settings.imageData.poster_sizes[0];
                    var poster_filepath = data.poster_path;
                    var poster_url = poster_base_url + poster_size + "/" + poster_filepath;
                    var html = settings.html + "<li><img src='" + poster_url + "' alt='Poster' /><a  class='ui-link-inherit'><h3 class='ui-li-heading'>" + data.title + "</h3><p class='ui-li-desc'><strong>" + data.tagline + "</strong></p><p class='ui-li-desc'>" + data.overview + "</p></a></li>";

                }
            }
            html = html + "</ul>";
            console.log(html);
            $('#content-add-title').html(html);
            $('#film-search-results').trigger("create");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm pretty new to using JSONP for cross domain calls so i'm not sure what's going wrong seeing as the first two call backs fire and it's only the last one that doesn't. any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a method called `insertFilmData` and can't find it. Presumably it will work if you define the function to be a method of the object which is a parameter to the ajax call, ie:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + filmId + '?api_key=XXX&append_to_response=' + settings.extras,
                async: false,
                jsonpCallback: 'insertFilmData',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(json) {
                    if (json) {
                        settings.html = html;
                        insertFilmData(json, settings);
                    }
                },
                insertFilmData: function(data, settings) {
                    var poster_base_url = settings.imageData.base_url;
                    var poster_size = settings.imageData.poster_sizes[0];
                    var poster_filepath = data.poster_path;
                    var poster_url = poster_base_url + poster_size + "/" + poster_filepath;
                    var html = settings.html + "<li><img src='" + poster_url + "' alt='Poster' /><a  class='ui-link-inherit'><h3 class='ui-li-heading'>" + data.title + "</h3><p class='ui-li-desc'><strong>" + data.tagline + "</strong></p><p class='ui-li-desc'>" + data.overview + "</p></a></li>";

                }

            });
```

Alternatively, you could just keep it as it is now, but change the line `jsonpCallback: 'insertFilmData',` to `jsonpCallback: insertFilmData,`. This will mean one of the arguments to the ajax call will be the function itself, not the name of the function. (And if I understand this correctly, it doesn't matter that the function definition is below this line, because it's a named function and it's in scope.)

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions neither worked. your second suggestion called the jsonp callback but the parameters for the callback are undefined inside the function. not sure how to pass the json from the $.ajax call and the settings object to the callback

Comment: I suppose that's a separate issue. Hmmm... the only thing I can see wrong with this code is the `async: false` part. From the jQuery documentation for `async`: "Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation." I would have hoped jQuery would throw an error, but apparently not. Try changing that and see what happens. (This is a wild guess, but you should probably change it anyway.)